# Chef : Pass parameters to a ruby_block in Chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

How do you pass parameters to a ruby_block in chef.

If I have

```
  notifies :create, "ruby_block[createErb]", :immediately
```

and I want pass a parameter (fileToConvert) to this ruby_block (createErb) at the time that I notify.

```
ruby_block "createErb" do
  block do
    ErbCreator.new(fileToConvert)
  end
  action :nothing
end
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer - you can't.

RubyBlock is a Chef resource, so it does not accept arbitrary parameters. In your example, I would recommend creating a Chef Extension (LWRP or HWRP):

In your resource:

```
# resources/erb_create.rb
actions :create
default_action :create

attribute :filename, name_attribute: true
# more attributes
```

And in your provider:

```
# providers/erb_create.rb
action(:create) do
  ErbCreator.new(new_resource.filename)
  # ... etc
end
```

Then in a recipe:

```
# recipes/default.rb
cookbook_erb_create 'filename'
```

You can [read more about LWRPs on the Chef Docs](http://docs.opscode.com/lwrp.html).